# Android Translate Animation inside fragment not working

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-animation

I have created a translation animation inside a fragment for listviews and it is working when I click on the list items in that fragment page but, it is not working when I visit some other fragment and come back and click list items no animation triggered,then I tried animation listeners only onAnimationStart() method got triggered and onAnimationEnd() did not get executed.
Also,I do not experience this problem in medium versions(like API level 8), only high(like API level 14,16,..) versions giving me this trouble.
I hope somebody will help me to get out of this issue..
Thanks in advance...
Here is my code,

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_certificate, container, false);
        Log.d("err", "onCreateView");



        // setContentView(R.layout.my_certificate);
        Constants.passcode_chk = 0;
        getReference();
        setclick();
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                .getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        if (resumeFlag == 0) {
            new RssLoadingTask_certificate().execute();
        } else {
            Log.d("err", "onCreateView else");
            if (list_no == 1) {
                try {
                    view.refreshDrawableState();
                    mainListView.clearAnimation();
                    mainListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mainListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Jemshid", "" + e.toString());
                }
                menuFlag = 0;
                lastPos = -1;
                animFlag = false;
                multi = false;
                Animating = false;

                tabimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.certificate_active_tab);
                setListing(arr_active_voucher);
                mainListView.onRefreshComplete();

            } else if (list_no == 2) {

                mainListView.clearAnimation();
                menuFlag = 0;
                lastPos = -1;
                animFlag = false;
                multi = false;
                Animating = false;
                tabimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.certificate_used_tab);
                setListing(arr_used_voucher);

                mainListView.onRefreshComplete();

            } else if (list_no == 3) {
                menuFlag = 0;
                lastPos = -1;
                animFlag = false;
                multi = false;
                Animating = false;
                tabimage.setImageResource(R.drawable.certificate_expired_tab);
                setListing(arr_expire_voucher);
                mainListView.onRefreshComplete();


            }
        }
        try {
            view.clearAnimation();
            view.refreshDrawableState();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return view;
    }
```

setListing method,

```
private void setListing(ArrayList<Voucher_list> arr) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        VoucherData my_data[] = new VoucherData[arr.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {

            ArrayList<Voucher_list> tmpp = arr;
            Voucher_list temp = tmpp.get(i);

            my_data[i] = new VoucherData(temp.Voucher_dealCertificateTitle,
                    temp.Voucher_voucherCode, temp.Voucher_dealTypeKey);

        }
        adapter = new ListVoucherAdapter(mActivity, R.layout.certificate_list,
                my_data, arr, mainListView);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mainListView.refreshDrawableState();
        mainListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        resumeFlag = 1;

    }
```